# How to convert constructor parameter in Java record?

Tags: java, jackson, record, dto

I have DTO class and I need to replace it with record equivalent.

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDTO {

    private Set<NotificationType> enabledSettings;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public MyDTO(final Set<String> enabledSettings) {
        this.enabledSettings = enabledSettings.stream()
                .map(s -> NotificationType.valueOf(s.toUpperCase()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

The problem is that actually I receive `Set<String>` but getter should be for `Set<NotificationType>`. As for now I don't see any solution.

Comment: Can you show your `NotificationType` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the record encapsulates `Set<NotificationType>` and you would like to pass `Set<String>` to form the encapsulated field, but due to the type erasure, the constructor accepting `Set<String>` cannot be used.

As long as you are not limited to `Set`, you can use a constructor with `Collection<String>`:

```java
public MyDTO(final Collection<String> enabledSettings) {
    this(enabledSettings.stream()
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .map(NotificationType::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to create a static factory method:

```
public record MyDTO(Set<NotificationType> enabledSettings) {

    public static MyDTO create(final Set<String> enabledSettings) {
        return new MyDTO(enabledSettings.stream()
            .map(s -> NotificationType.valueOf(s.toUpperCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Because constructor `MyDTO(Set<String> enabledSettings)` would have the same signature after type erasure as the required constructor `MyDTO(Set<NotificationType> enabledSettings)`, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
//**@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDTO {
    private Set<NotificationType> enabled settings;
    @JsonCreator(mode=JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public MyDTO(final Set<String>enabledSettings) {
        this.enabledSettings=enabledSettings.stream().maps-> NotificationType.valueOf(s.toUpperCase())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
//You should try once.(factory method)
public record MyDTO(Set<NotificationType> enabledSettings) {
    public static MyDTO create(final Set<String> enabledSettings) {
        return new MyDTO(enabledSettings.stream()
            .map(sk -> NotificationType.valueOf(sk.toUpperCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    }
}
```

- 

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).